# What is the current flow in a GPU?

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, hardware

Today, I was playing GTA 5 on my laptop. In the performance tab, I saw that my GPU(GTX 1650 with Max-Q design) power is 34 Watts and the voltage of GPU is 0.8v. So, according to P = VI, I = 42.5A. I guess this current is huge. So if this is incorrect, what is the typical current flow in a GPU circuit while gaming? And if I am interpreting this incorrectly, then what do they exactly mean by "GPU Voltage" and "GPU Power". Screenshot is included below.

[image]

Comment: Is it not difficult to read your monitor when it's rotated 90° like that?

Comment: The current is really that large.

Comment: Is this current normal?

Comment: no, the monitor is okay....i guess my camera didnt rotate

Comment: Image can be rotated using something like paint

Comment: yes i know, it can also be done simply with windows photos

Answer (score 3):

> So, according to P = VI, I = 42.5A. I guess this current is huge.

You have a relatively low power GPU. High-end devices can pull on the order of 500 amps, and it is not unheard of for a poor driver or unexpected load to burn out the voltage regulators by driving their current above what they can handle.

> And if I am interpreting this incorrectly, then what do they exactly mean by "GPU Voltage" and "GPU Power". Screenshot is included below.

A tiny amount of current flows whenever a transistor flips, and an even smaller amount leaks through them whenever they are powered. Across billions or tens of billions of gates that can add up to a lot of current. That screenshot is the power management interface letting you know how much current is being used. Multiply times the supply voltage and you get total power.